# i want to exchange data use case when

Tags: mysql

[image: table test data]

```
 UPDATE tb_test 
    set name =  
    ( CASE  
    WHEN (id = 1) THEN (select DISTINCT name from tb_test where id = 2) 
    WHEN (

id = 2) THEN (select DISTINCT name from tb_test where id = 1) 
END )
```

**Result:**

[SQL] UPDATE tb_test

```
set name =  
( CASE  
WHEN (id = 1) THEN (select DISTINCT name from tb_test where id = 2) 
WHEN (id = 2) THEN (select DISTINCT name from tb_test where id = 1) 
END )
```

`[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'tb_test' for update in FROM clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will work for you

```
  UPDATE tb_test
  set name =
    ( 
    CASE
         WHEN id = 1
         THEN (select * from (select DISTINCT name from tb_test where id = 2)t)
         WHEN id = 2
         THEN (select * from (select DISTINCT name from tb_test where id = 1)y) 
    END 
   );
```

Comment: @田躲躲 your welcome. Please accept this as a answer so it can help others to troubleshoot their problems

Answer (score 0):

in same table you can not `select` and `update` operation perform in same time

```
 UPDATE tb_test 
 set name =  
 (CASE  
    WHEN id = 1 THEN (select sub_query1.new_name from (select DISTINCT name as new_name from tb_test where id = 2 limit 1) as sub_query1 )   
    WHEN id = 2 THEN (select sub_query2.new_name from (select DISTINCT name as new_name from tb_test where id = 1 limit 1) as sub_query2) 
END);
```